# Redmine: fetching emails from POP3 under Windows

Tags: redmine

I have Redmine running locally under Windows 10.

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                3.4.6.stable
  Ruby version                   2.4.4-p296 (2018-03-28) [x64-mingw32]
  Rails version                  4.2.8
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               SQLite
SCM:
  Git                            2.16.2
  Filesystem                     
Redmine plugins:
  redmine_issues_tree            0.0.12
```

I try to fetch emails from a POP3 account. I use the following command:

```
rake redmine:email:receive_pop3 host=xxx.xxx.com port=995 ssl=1 username=uuu@yyy.com password=zzz RAILS_ENV=production unknown_user=accept no_permission_check=1 project=MyProject allow_override=project,tracker,status,priority move_on_success=read move_on_failure=failed --trace
```

The content of the email I have sent to the above mailbox is:

```
Project: MyProject
Tracker: Bug
Status: New
Priority: Normal
```

Executing the rake command as shown above I get:

```
** Invoke redmine:email:receive_pop3 (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute redmine:email:receive_pop3

C:\redmine-3.4.6>
```

The connection to the mailbox seem to work. But there is nothing happening in Redmine. No issue is added, nor is there any other changes. What could I try to find the problem?

My second question concerns the

```
move_on_success=read
```

and

```
move_on_failure=failed
```

options. Are these options only for IMAP accounts or do they work for POP3 as well? If they work for POP3 in which mailboxes or folders are the emails moved?

Comment: On pop3 you don't have move_on options, those are for IMAP servers... On pop3 it's only message read or not read...